# How to send syslog to graylog

Tags: logging, centos, send, syslog, graylog

we have many Centos clients (Centos 5-7). I want that all clients send logs via syslog to the graylog server. This works on clients where rsyslog is installed. But the old clients don't have rsyslog. They use syslog.

What should I change in the `/etc/syslog.conf` file to make it work?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can somebody help?

I tried this yet:
1.) I added the IP from the remote server (graylog server) to `/etc/syslog.conf: *.* @IP-ADDRESS`
2.) I add the -r Parameter in `/etc/sysconfig/syslog` to `SYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-r -m 0"`
3.) `service syslog restart`

But it doesn't work. I don't get any log on graylog server. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Use graylog-collector for the other clients :

My conf for graylog-collector :

```
server-url = "http://192.168.254.184:12900/"

inputs {
  win-eventlog-application {
    type = "windows-eventlog"
    source-name = "Application"
    poll-interval = "1s"
  }
  win-eventlog-system {
    type = "windows-eventlog"
    source-name = "System"
    poll-interval = "1s"
  }
  win-eventlog-security {
    type = "windows-eventlog"
    source-name = "Security"
    poll-interval = "1s"
  }
}

outputs {
  gelf-tcp {
    type = "gelf"
    host = "192.168.254.184"
    port = 12201
  }
}
```

Just creat an input in graylog2 interface for GELF format!

Answer (score 0):

do you use the old syslog or syslog-ng? if you use syslog you can't change the output format, but if you use syslog-ng try:

```
# Define TCP syslog destination.
destination d_net {
    syslog("graylog.example.org" port(514));
};
# Tell syslog-ng to send data from source s_src to the newly defined syslog destination.
log {
    source(s_src); # Defined in the default syslog-ng configuration.
    destination(d_net);
};
```