# Syslog UDP Input failed - rsyslog and graylog

Tags: udp, rsyslog, graylog

I have been trying to send logs from my Centos 8 virtual machine to a Graylog server using rsyslog. Unfortunately my UDP Syslog Input fails without any further description.

I have made sure to add this line to my rsyslog configuration file in `/etc/rsyslog.conf`:
`*.* @192.168.100.45:514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format`

Where `192.168.100.45` is the IP address of my Graylog server

I have made sure to allow communication on port 514/udp on **both** machines using firewall-cmd:

`firewall-cmd --add-port=514/udp --permanent`

`firewall-cmd --reload`

The output of `systemctl status rsyslog.service`:
[image]

The configuration of UDP Syslog Input on  my Graylog Server:
[image]

Where `192.168.100.40` is the IP address of my Centos 8 machine from which the logs should arrive.

Before anyone suggests, this post was not helpful: [How to send syslog to graylog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34911505/how-to-send-syslog-to-graylog)

I kindly ask for your help and wish you a nice day/night!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
The bind address should be set to default and not the IP address of the client.
Furthermore, I changed the port from default which was 514 to 3514 (saw it somewhere on the internet).

Also this line:

`*.* @192.168.100.45:514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format`

is wrong, there should be a double colon instead of a semicolon:
`*.* @192.168.100.45:514:RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format`

Most of this information was discovered by me in this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E1taHpbAgc

Cheers!